# Want to loop through a json array after selecting a dropdown box list

Tags: arrays, json, select, html-select

I want to be able to select a list of options from a dropdown box with "Station" values taken from json array -"smallData.json" (which I am able to do and it is working) and then produce a set of results from the same json array based on the specific "station" option chosen from the dropdown list (which is not working currently). I assume I may need a function to be called and loop through the array with the onchange method, however, I am not certain how that would work.

```
[
 {
   "ID": 1,
   "Station": "Carmichael Rd.",
   "Address": "54 Myers Rd.",
   "Monthly_CStore_Sales": "120,000",
   "Operator": "Michael Sears",
   "Top_SKU": "Hotdogs"
 },
 {
   "ID": 2,
   "Station": "Baillou Hill",
   "Address": "564 Jackson Ave.",
   "Monthly_CStore_Sales": "89000",
   "Operator": "Sarah Pikes",
   "Top_SKU": "Patties"
 },
 {
   "ID": 3,
   "Station": "Oakesfield",
   "Address": "42 Peterson St.",
   "Monthly_CStore_Sales": "150000",
   "Operator": "Yolanda Gray",
   "Top_SKU": "Chicken"
 }
 ]
```

**Code**

```
<select id="dmenu"></select>
<div id="optionT"></div>

<script>
let dropdown = document.getElementById('dmenu');
dropdown.length = 0;

let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
defaultOption.text = 'Choose Station';

dropdown.add(defaultOption);
dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

const url = './smallData.json';

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status === 200) {
    const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    let option;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = data[i].Station;

      dropdown.add(option);

      var optionText = "";
      for (x in data){
          optionText += '<ul>' +

            '<li>Station: '+ data.Station[x] +'</li>' +

            document.getElementById('optionT').innerHTML = optionText;
      }

    } else {
    // Reached the server, but it returned an error

}
}
request.onerror = function() {
  console.error('An error occurred fetching the JSON from ' + url);
};

request.send();
</script>
```

*Example:*
If I select for example: "Station Carmichael Road", all the key value pairs associated with that Station field I want to come up:

```
 "ID:1",
   "Address": "54 Myers Rd.",
   "Monthly_CStore_Sales": "120,000",
   "Operator": "Michael Sears",
   "Top_SKU": "Hotdogs"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show Station's data when a drop-down option is selected.

Add `onchange` event on your drop-down element.

```
<select id="dmenu" onchange="handleOnChange(this)"></select>
```

Then move your list-rendering logic to `handleOnChange()`

```
function handleOnChange(selectedDropdown) {
    // Find array element by "Station" value
    var station = data.find(function(element) {
        return element.Station == selectedDropdown.value;
    });

    // If station exists
    if (station) {
        // Show station's key-value in list
        let optionText = '<ul>';

        Object.keys(station).forEach(function(key) {
            optionText += '<li>' + key +': ' + station[key] +  '</li>';
            document.getElementById('optionT').innerHTML = optionText;
        });

        optionText += '</ul>';
    }
}
```

**Full Code**

```
<script>
function handleOnChange(selectedDropdown) {
    // Find array element by "Station" value
    var station = data.find(function(element) {
        return element.Station == selectedDropdown.value;
    });

    // If station exists
    if (station) {
        // Show station's key-value in list
        let optionText = '<ul>';

        Object.keys(station).forEach(function(key) {
            optionText += '<li>' + key +': ' + station[key] +  '</li>';
            document.getElementById('optionT').innerHTML = optionText;
        });

        optionText += '</ul>';
    }
}

let dropdown = document.getElementById('dmenu');
dropdown.length = 0;

let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
defaultOption.text = 'Choose Station';

dropdown.add(defaultOption);
dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

const url = './smallData.json';
let data;

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', url, true);

request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status === 200) {
        data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        let option;

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            option = document.createElement('option');
            option.text = data[i].Station;

            dropdown.add(option);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Reached the server, but it returned an error
    }
}
request.onerror = function() {
console.error('An error occurred fetching the JSON from ' + url);
};

request.send();
</script>
```

Comment: I believe you are going in the right direction, but I keep getting an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at handleOnChange (drop.html:59)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (drop.html:14)
handleOnChange @ drop.html:59
onchange @ drop.html:14